# fs unlink not deleting video untill server restart

Tags: node.js, fs, multer, delete-file

So this is my code

```
fs.unlink(`storage/videos/${videoId + path.extname(file.originalname)}`, err => {
   if (err) return console.log(err)
   console.log(`deleted video: ${videoId + path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
})
```

This thing console logs the deleted video but it won't remove it from folder until I won't do server restart, I used same code for image and It removes image immediately, Idk what's issue with video

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows, But what has it to do with my os

Comment: Windows has different file system semantics than most Unix file systems. If, for instance, the file is still being written, or even just open, it may not want to remove the file entry from the directory (as opposed to on Unix, where it's perfectly fine to remove files that are still "in use").

Comment: what can i do to remove it then

Comment: Don't think you can. But you should try and find out if it's actually caused by the file still being in use, I could be talking rubbish :) (I don't use Windows so can't recommend any tools)

Comment: no worries, I found the solution. I had to stop reading that video file before deleting it :)